# Lua api script change hold key to toggle

Tags: lua, logitech-gaming-software

Hey I want to modify this script, now I need to hold right mouse click to make to script run. I want to change it to toggle right click, then let it run when holding left click until i press right click again. Anyone know how to do this?

```
EnablePrimaryMouseButtonEvents(true);
 
function OnEvent(event, arg)
    if IsKeyLockOn("numlock" )then
        if IsMouseButtonPressed(3)then
            repeat  
                if IsMouseButtonPressed(1) then
                    repeat
                        MoveMouseRelative(1,7)
                        Sleep(30)
                    until not IsMouseButtonPressed(1)
                end             
            until not IsMouseButtonPressed(3)
        end     
    end
end
```

Comment: What have you tried? what issues are you having? Stack overflow is not a coding service, as your question is now it comes off like "I have this code that does y, can someone make it do x for me".

Comment: @Nifim - You are correct.  But there is one problem: there are no good tutorials on LGS.  I was learning it by reading manual (which is just a list of API functions) and googling for scripts written by other people.  It is impossible for a beginner programmer to learn LGS without help of others.

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff that's a fair point, but idk that SO is the right place for that interaction. I can see how someone with no clear place to go would end up here.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
local recoil_mode

function OnEvent(event, arg)
   if event == "PROFILE_ACTIVATED" then
      EnablePrimaryMouseButtonEvents(true)
   elseif event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_PRESSED" and arg == 2 then
      recoil_mode = not recoil_mode
   elseif event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_PRESSED" and arg == 1 and recoil_mode and IsKeyLockOn("numlock") then
      repeat
         MoveMouseRelative(1,7)
         Sleep(30)
      until not IsMouseButtonPressed(1)
   end
end
```

Comment: I just tested this and this works basicly on the primary gun as i wanted but not on the secondary gun (acts like no script works), seems weird Cant see a specific reason for this in the script tho

Comment: What is `the secondary gun`? How do you fire it?

Comment: Same way fired as the primary gun

Comment: Both guns are on LMB?